# why are there two std::allocator::construct functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

The standard gives two construct functions in `std::allocator<T>` for the placement new syntax underneath:

```
void construct( pointer p, const_reference val );  (1)  (until C++11)

template< class U, class... Args >
void construct( U* p, Args&&... args );            (2)  (since C++11)

1) Calls new((void *)p) T(val)
2) Calls ::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

Whats the difference between 1) and 2) except from the fact that we forward all arguments to the constructor in 2)
For what reason do we need 1)?

Imagine we would only have signature 2) , then passing the argument from the (non-existing) first one would result in calling:

```
::new((void *)p) T(std::forward<const_reference>val)
```

which should call the copy constructor  T(val) anyway? Here, I am asking me whats the point of having the additional signature 1)?
There is a difference one calls `new` the other one the global function `::new`

Thanks for shining some light in to this :-)

Comment: There is only one. "Until" and "since" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: ahh , ups, that resolved everything

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the excerpts you posted: one is pre-C++11 and one is post-C++11. `construct` is best expressed by perfect-forwarding arguments rather than calling the copy-constructor, but perfect-forwarding is only available in C++11, so we had to make do with the first option before this could be a reality.